# java codewars initiateRandTests expected:<false> but was:<true>

Tags: java, operating-system

This code passed all tests except one "initiateRandTests".I dont understand what is it. On the site 0 information about this or I cant understand it.

there is my code:

```
 public class XO {
  
  public static boolean getXO (String str) {
    int num = 0, x = 0, o = 0;
    int indX, indO;
    while(num < str.length()){
      indX = str.indexOf("x", num);
      indO = str.indexOf("o", num);
      if (indX == num){[enter image description here][1]
        x++;[enter image description here][2]
      }
      if (indO == num){
        o++;
      }
      num++;
    }
    return x == o;
  }
}
```

and there are tests:

```
public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething1() {
      assertEquals(true, XO.getXO("xxxooo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething2() {
      assertEquals(true, XO.getXO("xxxXooOo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething3() {
      assertEquals(false, XO.getXO("xxx23424esdsfvxXXOOooo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething4() {
      assertEquals(false, XO.getXO("xXxxoewrcoOoo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething5() {
      assertEquals(false, XO.getXO("XxxxooO"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething6() {
      assertEquals(true, XO.getXO("zssddd"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSomething7() {
      assertEquals(false, XO.getXO("Xxxxertr34"));
    }
}
```

as can you see all tests complited except last
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE2m9.png
this part I dont understand
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsfYr.png

Comment: You haven't shown the code for `initiateRandTests`.

Comment: yeah because I dont know what and where is it

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.
I found this in the [Codewars doc](https://docs.codewars.com/training/troubleshooting/).

> Some test or assertion libraries used by Codewars do not have a nice
> way to specify additional assertion messages for failed test cases, or
> authors did not think or care about adding these. If this is the case you will
> unfortunately have to debug in another way (for example by [printing
> test input](https://docs.codewars.com/training/troubleshooting/#print-output)), and perhaps [raise an issue](https://docs.codewars.com/training/troubleshooting/#post-discourse) about confusing
> assertion messages.